# Is there a way to make the numbers run in the correct order?

Tags: mysql

So when i run this query i created the numbers come back in the wrong order and i cannot figure out why

```
SELECT ones.num + tens.num + 1
FROM
 (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 num
 ) ones
CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 30 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 40 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 50 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 60 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 70 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 80 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 90 num
 ) tens;
```

Comment: Depends on what the "wrong" and "correct" order is. But [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) should help

Comment: Thank you so much!! i was pulling my hair as i am really new to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pretty much seems to come in order, however to remove any confusion
why don't you wrap it all as a subquery and use an order by clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ones.num + tens.num + 1 number
FROM
 (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 num
 ) ones
CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 30 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 40 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 50 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 60 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 70 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 80 num UNION ALL
  SELECT 90 num
 ) tens) final ORDER BY number DESC;
```